# How to filter out part-of-speech tag?

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

```
var sentence =" "/`` Do/VBP n't/RB cut/VB off/RP its/PRP$ power/NN ,/, "/'' he/PRP said/VBD ./. ";
var pattern = new Regex(@"/(?:[.,]|\p{Lu}+\b)");
var outcome = pattern.Replace(sentence, string.Empty);

//Output : "/`` Do n't cut off its$ power , "/'' he said .
```

How should I modify the pattern to produce expected output of:

"Don't cut off its power," he said.

Comment: You may wish to include where you got the POS marked up text from, so that the reference guide for that implementation can be used.

Comment: I constructed that sentence myself to conclude the problem I'm facing. I'm using OpenNLP to tag it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to answer, but the question needs some revision, since it doesn't compile:

```
var sentence = "\"Do/VBP n't/RB cut/VB off/RP its/PRP$ power/NN ,/, \" he/PRP said/VBD ./. ";
var pattern = new Regex(@"/.+?\s+");
var outcome = pattern.Replace(sentence, " ");

var expected = "\"Don't cut off its power,\" he said.";

var success = (outcome == expected);
Console.WriteLine(success);
Console.WriteLine(expected);
Console.WriteLine(outcome);
```

Comment: It doesn't compile because of the quotation marks. I've no idea how to fix it.